# A function which takes value from previous output

Tags: haskell

Hi I am new to haskell and I have a program

```
double x = case x of
 []   -> []
 x:xs -> (if (x*2 < 10) then [x*2] else [x*2 `div` 10 + x*2 `mod` 10]) ++ double xs
```

the problem I am having is I want to sum the answer given by this function and multiply the number by 7.

so lets say if i inputed double [1,2,3,4,5]

I would get [2,2,6,4,1] now i want to recall this into another function and add this together and multiply by 9. I am aware you can use **$** to attach functions but I am not sure how I would go about doing it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how would `double [1,2,3,4,5]` ever be `[2,2,6,4,1]`. When I run your code, I get `[2,4,6,8,1]`.

Also, is it 7 that you want to multiply by or 9? (I will assume 7 for the rest of the post.)

---

You can use `$` like this:

```
anotherFunction xs = sum xs * 7

double' x = anotherFunction $ double x
```

But it would be even better if you use `.` to *compose* your functions:

```
double'' = anotherFunction . double
```

Try it out and let me know if it does what you want!

Comment: this code gives an error • Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a ~ [a]
      Expected type: [a] -> [a]
        Actual type: [a] -> a

Comment: @Car Well, I do not see your type signatures, but yes, `double'` has a type similar to `[a] -> a`, unlike `double`. This is what one would expect, since a `sum` takes many numbers but gives only one.

Comment: @IgnatInsarov: no, unfortunately there is a mismatch, since you make a recursive call with `++ double' xs`, the compiler expects `double'` to return an `[a]`, but that will not happen, hence the infinite type `a ~ [a]`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Whoops. My brain must have been on vacation.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would suggest that you use a `map` here, instead of writing a recursive function yourself. It is clear that - for a list of elements - you generate a list of the same length where you map every element to another element. Here the "mapping function" is structured like:

```
f x | tx >= 10 = mod tx 10 + div tx 10
    | otherwise = tx
    where tx = 2*x
```

or even more compact:

```
f x = let tx = 2*x in min tx (mod tx 10 + div tx 10)
```

Now your `double` function can be expressed as:

```
double :: Integral i => [i] -> i
double = map f
    where f x = let tx = 2*x in min tx (mod tx 10 + div tx 10)
```

Now it produces:

```
Prelude> double [1..5]
[2,4,6,8,1]
```

Which is correct, based on your specifications. The only reasonable way to come up with the proposed list in the question, is by only processing values with an *odd* index (so the first, third, fifth, etc.).

Nevertheless, the core of the question is about post-processing. We can do this by using the [**`(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-46-) function:

```
sum7 :: Integral i => [i] -> i
sum7 = (7*) . sum . double
```

So for your given input, this produces:

```
Prelude> sum7 [1,2,3,4,5]
147
```

Comment: sorry but for this particular task I have been given instructions on not to use map

Comment: @Car: then I propose you construct your own `map`. The limitations of homework are not really part of the StackOverflow questions I think, since the aim is that other people can benefit from the questions and answers as well :).